# how can i validate data in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following date  `"13-05-2022"`

```
if (!validateDate(this.formGeral.value.data.singleDate?.formatted)) {
  this.errors.push('Data com formato inválido! Selecione a data de entrega novamente, se o problema persistir, favor entrar em contato com a nossa equipe.');
}
```

I use this validator, but it only validates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

```
export function validateDate(date: string) {
  const regex = new RegExp('([0-9]{4}[-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-]([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[0-1]{1}))');
  return regex.test(date);
}
```

How could I validate a date with `dd-mm-yyyy` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function validateDate(date) {
  const regex = new RegExp('([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[0-1]{1})[-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-]([0-9]{4})');
  return regex.test(date);
}

console.log(validateDate('2020-10-10')) // false
console.log(validateDate('10-10-2020')) // true
```